# AirPlay to Apple TV not displaying at full 1080 resolution?

Tags: appletv, airplay

I can successfully AirPlay from my M1 MacBook Pro to my 4k Apple TV connected to a 1920 x 1020 display... but I can only get a resolution of 1280 x 720:

[image: 720]

When I'm not AirPlay'ing and just using the Apple TV as one would typically use an Apple TV, I get full 1080.

How can I AirPlay at full 1080?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold down `Option` and click the *Scaled* button. Like magic, a whole bunch of new resolutions appear:

[image]

I found this here: [How To Set Custom Resolutions For External Displays In Mac OS X](https://www.alphr.com/custom-resolution-mac-osx/)

I have no idea why these resolutions don't appear initially... especially in my situation where 1080 is the native resolution.